# Create a new column pulls in values where a value equals a column name

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Apologies if the answer is already out there, I'm new to python and I couldn't find the answer.

That said, I'm playing with a pandas dataframe that has an aggregate sum and various other columns that break down where the sums are coming from.

I would like to come up with a code that creates a new column where the value of one column name's equals the field value of another and if it doesn't equal any column 0, and iterates over every row.

So for instance, I have the following simple table (My dataset is much larger so I would need something to iterate over several rows):

```
  Value  Aggregate  A  B  C
0     A          5  4  1  0
1     B          4  3  1  0
2     C         12  1  5  6
3     D          8  4  3  1
```

And would like to get the following:

```
Value Aggregate A   B   C   New Column
   A    5       4   1   0      4
   B    4       3   1   0      1
   C    12      1   5   6      6
   D    8       4   3   1      0
```

Comment: Will you please supply your sample data in a way that it can be copied and pasted?

Comment: You shouldn't have reverted my edit. Text sample data is much more helpful than pictures.

Comment: So sorry, this is the first time I've used Overstack...just getting used to it

Comment: " a new column where the value of one column name's equals the field value of another " can you give an example and elaborate on that?

Comment: So I have a column "value" that is composed of various strings ("A", "B", "C" etc.), and another column "Aggregate" which is the sum of the integers from the remaining columns (A, B, C)...what I would like to do is come up with a code that iterates through each row of  the "value" column and if it matches the name of a column (A, B, C) then I would like for it to insert that value and if it doens't then put 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lookup` but dealing with columns that don't exist:

```
m = df.Value.isin(df.columns)
df.loc[m, 'New Col'] = df.lookup(df[m].index, df[m].Value)
df['New Col'] = df['New Col'].fillna(0, downcast='int64')
```

---

```
  Value  Aggregate  A  B  C  New Col
0     A          5  4  1  0        4
1     B          4  3  1  0        1
2     C         12  1  5  6        6
3     D          8  4  3  1        0
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you know how to use this if the row labels and column don't have the same size? Looking to do this on a larger dataset and getting this error..."ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels"

Comment: @RyanO'Brien That error is a bit misleading. The two arguments you pass to `lookup` are `row_labels` and `col_labels`, in this case they are respectively `df[m].index` and `df[m].Value`. That is what needs to be the same shape, not the actual columns or rows in the DataFrame. Are you perhaps forgetting to slice one of them in your code with `[m]`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach with broadcasting:

```
cols = df.columns[-3:].values
mask = df['Value'].values[:,None] == cols
(df[cols]*mask).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
0    4
1    1
2    6
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @anky_91 I did, twice, and it got reverted twice :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it with 'stacking'.

create dataframe and make sure Value is the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',5,4,1,0],['B',4,3,1,0],['C',12,1,5,6],['D',8,4,3,1]], columns=['Value','Aggregate Leads', 'A','B','C'])
df.set_index('Value', inplace=True)

df
Out[154]: 
       Aggregate Leads  A  B  C
Value                          
A                    5  4  1  0
B                    4  3  1  0
C                   12  1  5  6
D                    8  4  3  1
```

stack the columns and reset the index:

```
temp = df[['A','B','C']].stack().reset_index()
```

compare index and column names to get values and join back into dataframe:

```
df.join(temp[temp.Value==temp.level_1].set_index('Value').iloc[:,-1]).fillna(0)

Out[156]: 
       Aggregate Leads  A  B  C    0
Value                               
A                    5  4  1  0  4.0
B                    4  3  1  0  1.0
C                   12  1  5  6  6.0
D                    8  4  3  1  0.0
```